# Android Material Design Divider Color

Tags: android

Following [color UI application](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-ui-color-application) of Material design i want to use an divider for the white theme. Guide 
[told me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZirhN.png)
that divider have 12% of white color, but **how i can define 12% of white color divider in xml** layout file?

[image]

Comment: to me it looks like they refer to the alpha channel. So the hex of the divider colour is #1FFFFFFF

Comment: @Blackbelt Yes! You're right. You hasten to delete your answer. Re-create - i will accept it.

Comment: I undelete it. Thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`12%` refers to the alpha channel. The max alpa is 255, and 12% of 255 is 31. Hex of 31 is 1F. So the color is `#1FFFFFFF`

Comment: `#1fffffff` is %12 white, for dark themes. #1f000000 is %12 black, for light themes.

Comment: How can you choose latter `FFF` or `000` based on the current active theme? For e.g. if Light Theme is active, display 12% black and if Dark Theme is active, display 12% white. Can this be done through XML? As changing Light theme to Dark in `styles.xml` changes background and text color according to theme in XML Preview. How can I implement it in my XML on a `View`(to be used as a divider).

Answer (score 28):

You can also use the official color which is also [used in the *Settings* app](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/master/res/layout/dashboard_tile.xml):

```
<View android:id="@+id/tile_divider"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="1dp"
      android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical" />
```

The important line is:

```
android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can very simply define the alpha in the color definition of the divider(or any other view) in your xml:

```
  android:color="#1FFFFFFF"
```

When defining the color of a view in android, the format can be either #RRGGBB or #AARRGGBB, where AA is the hex alpha value. FF would be fully opaque and 00 would be full transparent.

Dynamically

If you need to dynamically alter the opacity in your code, use

```
component.getBackground().setAlpha(128);  // 50% transparent
```

Where the INT ranges from 0 (fully transparent) to 255 (fully opaque).

Answer (score 0):

Its not 12% of white but 12% of your color scheme you are using ;)